# Removing the [modification] meta-tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[modification](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modification) seems like a meta-tag, as it doesn't really describe the content of the question. Also, there are only four questions under it, and two of them have been closed.

Please burninate the useless [modification](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modification) meta-tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were just 4 questions tagged so, just went and removed them from the questions. The tag will be auto deleted soon